# css transition wordpress twenty fourteen

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm creating a wordpress site with a child theme of twenty fourteen.
I wanted to fade in transitions and found this:
[ease in transition of submenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679668/ease-in-transition-of-submenu)

The answer works but:

1. For level 2 menus (a submenu under submenu), the items fly in from left to right, rather than just 'appearing out of thin air' - how do I fix this?
2. The transition has affected the mobile display version - how do i stop this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You don't want the animation on mobile but only on PC

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes that's one problem - no animation on mobile.
The other one is that, from the main menu, the drop down "appears" fine. But then a submenu from an item of the main menu will "fly in" from the left instead of just "appearing" from behind.

Comment: *Yes that's one problem - dont want animation on mobile.

Comment: @Jon you can use media query and write 'transition:none'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself as the sub-menu was at -999em in parent theme:

```css
/* Smooth transition of menus */
    .primary-navigation ul li:hover > ul, .primary-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
      opacity:1; 
    }

    .primary-navigation ul ul{
     transition: 1s;
   opacity:0;
    }

/* Submenus to slide out of submenus */
    .primary-navigation ul ul ul{
    top: 0px;
    left: 150px;
    }

/* Mobile nav menu to always show and not require hover */   
@media (max-width: 782px) {
    .primary-navigation ul ul{
     transition: 1s;
   opacity:1;
    }
}
```